# Running two methods (with arguments) simultaneously?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a Python-script where I want to run two methods simultaneously. I tried the following, but unfortunately, threads/processes only run simultaneously if there is no argument. So how can I solve this problem?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def download_from_file(filename):
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        links = [line.strip() for line in open(filename)]

        for link in links:
            Process(target = standard_download(link)).start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but unfortunately, threads/processes only run simultaneously if there is no argument.

Nope, that's not the problem.

The problem is that you're calling `standard_download(link)`, then passing the result of that call as the `target` argument. That's not what you want; you want to pass the function itself, and the arguments, to the `Process` object so that it can call them. That's exactly what the `args` parameter is for, as shown in [most of the examples for `multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class). In your case:

```
Process(target=standard_download, args=(link,)).start()
```

Or, you can always build a zero-argument function with `lambda` or `partial`, of course:

```
Process(target=functools.partial(standard_download, link)).start()
```

As a side note, just creating, starting, and leaking a bunch of child processes is a bad idea. You probably want to store them all in a list, and then `join` them all (whether immediately, or later). For example:

```
def download_from_file(filename):
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        links = [line.strip() for line in open(filename)]

        for link in links:
            p = Process(target=standard_download, args=(link,))
            p.start()
            yield p

processes = list(download_from_file(filename))
# later, when we need to wait until we're done with all the downloads
for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked out for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You want the args keyword argument:

```
Process(target = standard_download, args=(link,)).start()
```